# Class Inheriting Tkinter LabelFrame Not Displaying Contents

Tags: python, python-3.x, inheritance, tkinter

As the title says, I've created a class that inherits from tkinter's LabelFrame (BatteryCapacityLFrame), and I'm trying to initialize it such that it will display like a LabelFrame. However, when I run the code the Battery tab doesn't display a LabelFrame. How do I fix this (what I presume to be) inheritance issue?

Code:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk
from tkinter import *

class PanelManager(tk.Tk):
    def __init__ (self):
        #initializing tkinter within initialization function
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)
        self.title("Combat Robotics Calculator")
        self.panel_manager = ttk.Notebook(self)
        self.add_battery_tab("Batteries")
        self.add_tab("Pulleys")
        self.add_tab("Drive System")
        self.add_tab("Weapon System")

    def add_tab(self, title):
        tab_frame = Frame(self.panel_manager)
        self.panel_manager.add(tab_frame, text = title)
        self.panel_manager.pack()

    def add_battery_tab(self, title):
        battery_tab = BatteryTab(self)
        self.panel_manager.add(battery_tab, text = title)
        self.panel_manager.pack()


    def run(self):
        self.mainloop()


class BatteryTab(tk.Frame):
        def __init__ (self, master):

            tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
            #Capacity Calculator
            capacity_calcf = BatteryCapacityLFrame(self)
            capacity_calcf.grid(column = 1, row = 1, sticky = "news")

#I'm trying to initialize the class here, not sure what's going wrong
class BatteryCapacityLFrame(tk.LabelFrame):
    def __init__ (self, master):
        tk.LabelFrame.__init__(self, master)
        self.config(text = "Battery Capacity Calculator")


root_window = PanelManager()
root_window.run()
```

Thank you all so much for your time!

Answer (score 0):

You need to add something to the labelframe for it to show up.

```
class BatteryCapacityLFrame(tk.LabelFrame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        tk.LabelFrame.__init__(self, master)
        self.config(text="Battery Capacity Calculator")

        tk.Label(self, text='Test message.').grid()
```